# Exhibiting $\text{Aut}(N|L)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $N=:\mathbb{Q}(\mathcal{R}_{x^5-100})$, $L=:\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$, where $\zeta_5$ is a primitive $5^{th}$-root of unity, and $\Gamma:=\text{Aut}(N|\mathbb{Q})$.
>
> 1) Prove that $\text{Aut}(N|L)<\Gamma$ is cyclic with order $5$ and is a normal subgroup.
>
> 2) Prove that $\text{Aut}(N|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{100}))<\Gamma$ is cyclic with order $4$ and is not a normal subgroup.

I already know that $\text{Aut}(N|L)$ must be cyclic, whose order divides $5$. Since $N|L$ is clearly non trivial, then $|\text{Aut}(N|L)|=5$.

I can also prove that $[N:\mathbb{Q}]=20$, so that $[N:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{100})]=4$, and that $\text{Aut}(N|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{100}))$ must be cyclic.

But I'm having trouble to prove normality in 1) and non-normality in 2), because I can't exhibit the automorphisms. For example, what are the possibilities for $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(N|L)$? Since $N$ is generated by $\{1, \sqrt[5]{100}, ..., (\sqrt[5]{100})^{4}\}$ as an $L$-vector space, I know that $\sigma(\sqrt[5]{100})=(\sqrt[5]{100})^k$ where $k=1, 2, 3$ or $4$ are possibilities for $\sigma$. But there is still one possibility missing, and I can't find it.

I can't exhibit the automorphisms of $\text{Aut}(N|\mathbb{Q})$ either, and it seems complicated. How am I supposed to tackle this problem? Thanks!

Comment: The identity is $k=1$ , no?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you haven't proven cyclicity for the second case since you have only confirmed the order. To see it *is* cyclic, note that the automorphisms:

$$\begin{cases} \sqrt[5]{100}\mapsto\sqrt[5]{100} \\
\zeta_5\mapsto \zeta_5^k && 1\le k\le 4 \end{cases}$$

work for those purposes. To see one is normal and the other isn't, just use the fundamental theorem of Galois theory:  since $\Bbb Q(\zeta_5)$ is Galois and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]{100})$ is not, the corresponding stabilizer subgroups have the corresponding normality properties.

Also, your candidate automorphisms are a bit off:  $\text{Aut}(N|L)$ is composed of

$$\sigma_k:\begin{cases}\sqrt[5]{100}\mapsto\zeta_5^k\sqrt[5]{100} && 0\le k\le 4 \\
\zeta_5\mapsto \zeta_5 \end{cases}$$